# Is there a ready solution to handle a jstree within a mCustomScrollbar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

I have a `jsTree` within a `mCustomScrollbar`, theese both dont like each other - if it goes to scroll while drag. altough I found a solution - modifying both .js, I wonder if there is a solution "out of the box"

The point is, that jstree, seaches for standard HTML/CSS scroll logic, while mCustonScollbar hides this firmly.

That means, that if you drag on the edge of the (tree-) controll, the whole document scrolls, instead of the custom scollbar container, it belongs to.

**edit**: Is there any ready solution, to get these both work together?

Comment: I have not worked with mCustomScrollBar, but as the creator of jsTree I thought I'd share how jstree works - it looks for containers, which have a `scrollHeight` that is greater than their `offsetHeight` - any custom scrollbar lib that respects those properties and listens for changes will work nicely with jstree. I doubt there is a more universal way for me to solve this, but I am open to ideas.

Comment: @vakata: mCustomScrollBar is - like your brilliant - an other diamont in plugins. I did not find a way to just change one :-(, theese both, allthough smooth and seamless, dont "like each other" - just a different way to say "ok, this container (div) is mine"

Comment: @vakata: 
 
how to share the edits I made? (btw. after hating - I now love jstree - I think I stepped behind your logic to programm)

Comment: I know jstree has a steep learning curve, I am trying to improve this :) As for sharing any improvements - jstree has a public repo on github where you can create pull requests. If you think everyone can benefit from changes you made to jstree - create a pull request and I will review it.